# Alternative / Less Verbose Way to Write Parent / Child CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child

I have a div that I can only select via this method in CSS.

```
#parent-div #child-div {// styles}
```

I want to change all of the h1, h2, h3, and p tags in the child div, which up until now I would do as follows:

```
#parent-div #child-div h1, #parent-div #child-div h2, #parent-div 
#child-div h3, #parent-div #child-div p {
//styles
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  It seems such a waste of time to type #parent-div #child-div over and over again. Logically I would like to do #parent-div #child-div > h1, h2, h3, p but I know this won't work.

Any ideas on how to abbreviate this would be wonderful? I have big site with lots of CSS that needs changing / styling where I need to use multiple selectors.

Comment: `#parent-div #child-div > *` targets all immediate children inside `child-div`

Comment: This is where CSS preprocessors really come in handy. I know it's not a direct answer to your question, but this could be a lot less verbose if you used something like LESS or SCSS (at the expense of more configuration and needing to run a watcher to build your CSS whenever a file changes).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking to refactor working code belong on the Code Review site, not the Stack Overflow site.

Comment: It's not off topic at all @TylerH.  I'm having to code lots of new CSS as well as change legacy CSS - it's how to use code more efficiently via the CSS specification. It has already generated some helpful / useful comments.  Just because you can't contribute anything positive to this subject doesn't mean you have to be vindictive.

Comment: @EmilyChewy, Tyler is a huge contributor to this site. I don't think he was being vindictive, just following the guidelines. Anyway, what other elements are descendants of `#child-div`?

Comment: @Michael_B: To be fair, the canned comment starts with "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because..." This is not the first time somebody has pointed out the unnecessarily vindictive tone of that opening line, and now we have proof that such a perception is not just theoretical.

Comment: @EmilyChewy I meant no offense by it (nor could my tone possibly be vindictive... I don't think our paths have ever crossed before, so I could hardly be out for revenge against you). Your question was simply one that I viewed as off-topic. Even disregarding that, your question is both unclear and fairly broad. Luckily, BoltClock knew of a good duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this experimental feature `:any`. It is currently supported on gecko based and a few webkit based browsers.

For instance :

```
#parent-div > #child-div > :-moz-any(h1, h2, h3, p){
  /*stuff*/
}
```

Note that it is in the process of being standardized as `:matches`.

There isn't any other way around it that I'm aware of.

To learn more about it, see [css :any @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a reverse approach.

Instead of targeting elements, exclude elements.

You'll need to know the other element types that are descendants of the child div.

So if you want to style the `h1`, `h2`, `h3` and `p` tags, try this:

```
#parent-div #child-div *:not(h4):not(h5):not(h6):not(div):not(span):not(nav):not(section)
```

However, if the element types are too many, unknown or unpredictable, then your original method looks perfectly fine.

```
#parent-div #child-div h1,
#parent-div #child-div h2,
#parent-div #child-div h3,
#parent-div #child-div p
```

Comment: Thanks Michael that's good to know.

Comment: Feasible, but you would need an exhaustive list of tags that are not the ones we want to style, which can be pretty long to do/write and can possibly be longer than declaring individually each desired case.

Comment: @Vivick, maybe. Or maybe not. It could just be one or two tags in there. That's why I presented this option.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent and child `div`s are both targeted by `id`s, (presuming you're using `id`s properly and only have one instance of each) you can omit the `#parent-div` identifier, because `#child-div` is sufficient.

In many cases, your properties will be inherited (like font color and font size) based on [specificity](https://specificity.keegan.st) of the rule and inheritence on the page. This means that you can likely omit a lot of the declarations on the children of `#child-div` by making those properties of `#child-div` itself (and only overwriting them further down the chain where necessary).

Also, like @kukkuz suggested, if you're trying to apply the same properties to all direct children of `#child-div`, then you can use `#child-div > *`.